# Still images to video for storage - But back to still images for viewing

Tags: ffmpeg, jpeg, h.264, compression

Using ffmpeg I can take a number of still images and turn them into a video. I would like to do this to decrease the total size of all my timelapse photos. But I would also like to extract the still images for use at a later date.

In order to use this method:
 - I will need to correlate the original still image against a frame number in the video.
 - And I will need to extract a thumbnail of a given frame number in a
   video.

But before I go down this rabbit hole, I want to know if the requirements are possible using ffmpeg, and if so any hints on how to accomplish the task.

note: The still images are timelapse from a single camera over a day, so temporal compression will be measurable compared to a stack of jpegs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use ffmpeg to create a video from a sequence of images, the images aren't affected in any way.  You should still be able to use them for what you're trying to do, unless I'm misunderstanding your question.

Edit: You can use ffmpeg to create images from an existing video.  I'm not sure how well it will work for your purposes, but the images are pretty high quality, if not the same as the originals.  You'd have to play around with it to make sure the extracted images are exactly the same as the input images as far as sequential order and naming, but if you take fps into account, it should work.

The command to do this (from the ffmpeg [documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-do-I-encode-movie-to-single-pictures_003f)) is as follows:

> ffmpeg -i movie.mpg movie%d.jpg

Comment: I want to throw away the original stack of jpegs and instead extract frames from the movie when ever i need an individual still image.

Comment: It's the notation to show which files are going to be the input in the process.  Any file directly after the "-i" is included as an input.